# How can i create an asp.net-mvc3 project via an asp.net-webform project template(do not install asp.net-mvc3-dlls and asp.net-mvc3-vs-tool)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I do not want to install asp.net-mvc3-dlls and asp.net-mvc3-vs-tool because my remote server do not have asp.net-mvc-dlls.

I only have asp.net webform project template in visual studio 2010.

Now I have created an asp.net web project. And I have downloaded these dll into project/Bin folder:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
System.Web.Helpers.dll
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
System.Web.WebPages.dll
...
```

What is the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully implemented **MVC4** in asp.net "website project" but MVC3 shouldn't look much difference. I'll just give you an overview of TODO.

1.manually update web.config dependency and compilation

here is *MVC4* assemblies config you have to replace public key token for version3 or just google for MVC3 web.config and merge into your existing one.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    ....
```

also register .NET ISAPI handler and runtime assemblies

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

2.register default route in global.aspx `Application_Start()`

```
    RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

since you didn't update VS you can't compile *Razor* view engine. use only classic `*.aspx` View

Answer (score 0):

since you "do not want to install ... because my remote server do not have asp.net-mvc-dlls.",
recreate and ensure your web project is using webform.

if those dlls still appear in the bin with this newly created webform project, let them be, and just upload them, treat them as helper/additional .net dll.